# Converting images from ATT database to Matrix of pixel values

Tags: r, pca

I am currently working on a code for facial recognition in R. I am using the 400 images from the att database:
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html

I have already read in all 400 images (See code below).
I was wondering how I could go about extracting the pixel values for these images into a matrix of pixel values to use for facial recognition.

MY CODE SO FAR:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(imager)
library(magick)
library(png)

Load_Image <- function(fn) {
  img <- image_read(fn)

  img_bmp <- img[[1]][1,,]
  img_dims <- attributes(img_bmp)$dim
  imga <- as.cimg(as.integer(img_bmp),x=img_dims[1],y=img_dims[2])
  list(imga,img_dims)
}


A <- list.files(path="./orl_faces/")

B <- A[grep(pattern="^s",A)]
C <- paste("./orl_faces/",B,"/",sep="")
Clen <- length(C)

ImgDB <- data.frame(person=character(),imgfile=character(),imgfile_fq=character(),
                    xdim=integer(),ydim=integer(),bmpindx=integer())


Imgs <- vector("list",400)
bmpindx <- 1

for(i in 1:Clen) {
  img_files <- list.files(path=C[i],full.names=FALSE)
  img_files_full <- paste(C[i],img_files,sep="")
  for(j in (1:length(img_files))) {
    Img <- Load_Image(img_files_full[j])
    ImgDB <- rbind(ImgDB,data.frame(person=B[i],imgfile=img_files[j],
                                imgfile_fq=img_files_full[j],xdim=Img[[2]][[1]],
                                ydim = Img[[2]][[2]],bmpindx = bmpindx))
    Imgs[[bmpindx]] <- Img[[1]]
    bmpindx <- bmpindx + 1
  }
}

save(ImgDB,Imgs,file="orl_faces.Rdata")
```